# How can we make the first option value in <select> display by default for values coming dynamically

Tags: html, angularjs, meteor, drop-down-menu, html-select

I had a  field where the options for it comes dynamically.Now I want to display the first option value in the  field by default.Can someone help .

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
 <select name="trader" class="form-control" id="select" ng-model="$root.customerDetails.traderType" 
ng-options="traderTypeObj.description for traderTypeObj in traderTypes track by traderTypeObj.type"  ng-required="true">                  
   </select>
  </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong syntax for `ng-model`.It should be `ng-model="customerDetails.traderType"`.Remove the $root.

For setting default value in select box use `ng-init`.`ng-init="customerDetails.traderType = traderTypes[0]"`

```
<select ng-init="somethingHere = options[0]" 
        ng-model="somethingHere" 
        ng-options="option.name for option in options">
</select>
```